# Passing javascript variable to JSP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to pass javascript variable "textVal" to a jsp.I just can't figure correct syntax. My code is like this

```
 function show(textVal){
   AJAX.onreadystatechange = handler;
   AJAX.open("POST","service.jsp",true);
   AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   AJAX.send("fname='+textVal+'");
};
```

How do i pass this textVal to service.jsp

Comment: If you are able to use jQuery, I would strongly recommend it, as ajax functionality is one of the areas where jQuery shines.

Comment: That's not how AJAX works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @SLaks What's wrong with the code? Looks fine to me except for the param passed to `.send()`

Comment: @Ian: `AJAX` is not defined?

Comment: @SLaks Exactly, what is `AJAX`? It's probably not safe for me to assume it's an `XMLHttpRequest` instance, but it's also not safe to assume it's not. They seem to have the basics down - using `onreadystatechange`, `open`, `setRequestHeader`, and `send` properly. It might've been easier to ask and figure out what `AJAX` was instead of thinking they know nothing

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the extra quotes. You can use:

```
AJAX.send("fname="+encodeURIComponent(textVal));
```